# How do I move files into folders with similar names in Unix?

Tags: bash, unix, filenames, mv

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before, I just didn't know how to word it as a search query.

I have a set of folders that look like this:

```
Brain - Amygdala/                 Brain - Spinal cord (cervical c-1)/  Skin - Sun Exposed (Lower leg)/
Brain - Caudate (basal ganglia)/  Lung/                                Whole Blood/
```

I also have a set of files that look like this:

```
Brain_Amygdala.v7.covariates_output.txt                  Skin_Not_Sun_Exposed_Suprapubic.v7.covariates_output.txt
Brain_Caudate_basal_ganglia.v7.covariates_output.txt     Skin_Sun_Exposed_Lower_leg.v7.covariates_output.txt
Brain_Spinal_cord_cervical_c-1.v7.covariates_output.txt  Whole_Blood.v7.covariates_output.txt
```

As you can see, the files do not perfectly match up with the directories in their names. For example, `Brain_Amygdala.v7.covariates_output.txt` is not totally identical to `Brain - Amygdala/`. Even if we were to excise the tissue name from the covariates file, `Brain_Amygdala` is formatted differently from its corresponding folder.

Same with `Whole Blood/`. It is different from `Whole_Blood.v7.covariates_output.txt`, even if you were to isolate the tissue name from the covariates file `Whole_Blood`.

What I want to do, however, is to move each of these tissue files to their corresponding folder. If you notice, the covariate files are named after the tissue leading up to the first dot `.` in the file name. They are separated by underscores `_`. **How I was thinking about approaching this was** to break up the first few words leading up to the first `.` of the file name so that I can easily move it to its corresponding file.

e.g.

`Brain_Amygdala.v7.covariates_output.txt` -> `Brain*Amygdala` [mv]-> `Brain*Amygdala/`

a) I'm not sure how to isolate the first words of a file name leading up to the first `.` in a filename

b) if I were to do that, I don't know how to insert a wildcard in between each word and match that to the corresponding folder.

***However,*** I am completely open to other ways of doing something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a full answer, but it should address some of your concerns:

a) to isolate the first word of a string, leading up to the first `.`: use [Parameter Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

```
string=Brain_Amygdala.v7.covariates_output.txt
until_dot=${string%%.*}
echo "$until_dot"
```

will output `Brain_Amygdala` (which we saved in the variable `until_dot`).

b) You may want to use the `${parameter/pattern/string}` parameter expansion:

```
# Replace all non-alphabetic characters by the glob *
glob_pattern=${until_dot//[^[:alpha:]]/*}
echo "$glob_pattern"
```

will output (with the same variables as above) `Brain*Amygdala`

c) To use all of this: it's probably a good idea to determine the possible targets first, and do some basic checks:

```
# Use nullglob to have non matching glob expand to nothing
shopt -s nullglob
# DO NOT USE QUOTES IN THE FOLLOWING EXPANSION:
# the variable is actually a glob!
# Could also do dirs=( $glob_pattern*/ ) to check if directory
dirs=( $glob_pattern/ )

# Now check how many matches there are:
if ((${#dirs[@]} == 0)); then
    echo >&2 "No matches for $glob_pattern"
elif ((${#dirs[@]} > 1)); then
    echo >&2 "More than one matches for $glob_pattern: ${dirs[@]}"
else
    echo "All good!"
    # Remove the echo to actually perform the move
    echo mv "$string" "${dirs[0]}"
fi
```

I don't know how your data will effectively conform to these, but I hope this answer actually answers some of your questions! (and to learn more about parameter expansions, do read — and experiment with — the link to the reference I gave you).

Comment: Looking at it again, I overlooked the glob part in c): might want `dirs=( $glob_pattern/ )` or even `dirs=( $glob_pattern*/ )`, and/or before the `mv`, check that the destination is indeed a directory.

Comment: Just one issue: I get a successful message when I run the script, but when I check inside of the folders, I do not see anything. I think it's because Unix treats `Brain - Amygdala/` as three separate entities (`Brain`, `-`, and `Amygdala/`). Is there anyway when `echo mv "$string" "${dirs[0]}"` fires off for `"${dirs[0]}"` to still be enclosed in quotes? Better yet, is there a way to do this and at the same time remove the whitespaces found in the directory names? Thanks for your help. This is becoming very complicated and I'm just tempted to include the file and directory names in `mv`

Comment: What I'm getting now is `mv Brain_Spinal_cord_cervical_c-1.v7.covariates_output.txt Brain - Spinal cord (cervical c-1)/` when I want it to be `mv Brain_Spinal_cord_cervical_c-1.v7.covariates_output.txt "Brain - Spinal cord (cervical c-1)/"`

Comment: @CelineDion Don't worry about the spaces: it's the `echo` statement that strips the quotes off. The `mv` statement will receive the two arguments given: everything I wrote is properly quoted so as to work as wanted.